# What is the Mac equivalent of AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos, audio, core-audio

I am porting an iPhone app to Mac. On iPhone I use `AVAudioPlayer` for playing sounds, but it doesn't exist on Mac.  What would be the Mac equivalent for playing audio (hopefully as simple as AVAudioPlayer so I can port my app easily)?

Additionally, are there any open source libraries / samples / wrappers available for playing music and sound files on Mac?

Comment: I am using AudioQueues is it ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH3-SW1):

> Core Audio is designed to handle all audio needs in Mac OS X. You can use Core Audio to generate, record, mix, edit, process, and play audio.

Comment: Core Audio also exists on the iPhone. It's the low-level counterpart to AVAudioPlayer on iOS and NSSound on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 9):

As of OS X 10.7, AVAudioPlayer is available on the Mac and [Apple recommends using this wherever possible.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thats great... Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what capabilities you need, Core Audio might be unnecessarily complex.  The obvious simple way is NSSound.  It's also possible to use a hidden QTMovieView to play sound.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a framework for audio playback, called SFBAudioEngine: http://github.com/sbooth/SFBAudioEngine

It might be a bit more than you're looking for, but it is more capable than NSSound and supports formats (FLAC, Musepack, Ogg Vorbis) that Core Audio doesn't handle natively.

Comment: Does your framework support conversion to FLAC format? I desperately need that converter to implement Google's speech recognition based services in my app.

Comment: It doesn't support explicit conversion from one format to another, but you can use it to decode FLAC to PCM.